# How to fetch rows as unnamed tuples with SQLAlchemy (v1.4)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy 1.4, with the "future mode" enabled to increase compatibility with the future SQLAlchemy 2.0 (although I still don't have 100% compatibility enabled, according to warnings enabled by the `SQLALCHEMY_WARN_20` environment variable).

Right now I'm doing queries like this:

```py
with self.__db_engine.connect() as conn:
    rs = conn.execute(
        get_jobs_df_query.where(jobs_cols.target_market_id == target_market_id)
    )
    rows = rs.fetchall()
```

and `rows` becomes a list of "dicts" (although the underlying object is probably something else), so I can access its fields by using string indices, like this:

```py
row_0_field_x = rows[0]["x"]
```

This is really nice most of the times, but I need/want (for some specific cases) to access rows as if they were unnamed tuples, without caring about the name of each column. My main reason is performance, and easier interoperability with other libraries (like `numpy`) without having to introduce too much glue code.

Is there any easy way to directly obtain such unnamed tuples?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: IIRC, the results function as namedtuples, so you should be able to access by index already?

Comment: It seems to work, yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment to the question, your code (with `engine.future=True`) will return each row as an object (`<class 'sqlalchemy.engine.row.Row'>`) that behaves like a named tuple. However, if you really need a plain tuple you can just convert it:

```py
with engine.begin() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(
        sa.text("SELECT 'Alfa' as foo, 'Bravo' as bar")
    ).fetchone()
    print(type(result))  # <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.row.Row'>
    result = tuple(result)
    print(type(result))  # <class 'tuple'>
    print(result)  # ('Alfa', 'Bravo')
```

Comment: Hm isn't this working because you are using `.text(query)`? Doesn't that make it not use the ORM style but rather the Core style? When I do this, I still get the objects in the tuple, not the fields of the object.